# javascript won´t affect xmlhttprequest data?

Tags: javascript, razor

I have this javascript code:

```
function ajax(str) {
var xmlhttp;
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("c-c").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("c-c").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
if (str.length == null){
    document.getElementById("c-c").innerHTML("");
}else{
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "search.cshtml/" + str, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

}
```

Which will display data from this file called search.cshtml into another same file called users.cshtml:

```
<div class="c_c1" id="c_c1">

<ul>
<li class="c1">Students</li>

    @foreach (var nom in sql){
     <li><img alt="miniatura"  src="@Href("~/Photo/Thumbnail2", nom.UserId, new { size="small" })" class="thumbnail-border thumb22" />@nom.Nombre @nom.Apellido</li>
}


<li class="c1">Subjects</li>
@foreach (var sub in sql2){
     <li class="hola"><img alt="miniatura"  src="@Href("~/Photo/Thumbnail", sub.Sub_Id,    new { size="large" })" class="d" />@sub.Subject</li>
}

</ul>

</div>
```

My problem is that, the javascript that I use on the users.cshtml that affect the classes from the search.cshtml file, for example $("c_c1").width(); etc (that type of javascript, not the one of the xmlhttprequest) will not work. is like if the other javascript does not recognize the data that is inserted into the users.cshtml file. Whats the problem? I have tried putting the  link into the header of every file and it still wont affect THAT data.

Answer (score 0):

How old is this code?

Well, you need to understand that you are trying to work with an element that doesn't exist. Every reference to this will return null:

```
 document.getElementById("c-c")
```

You don't have an element with an Id of `c-c` in your markup. Given the class and Id names in your markup, it is difficult to determine what exactly you are trying to do... If you're looking to work with an element which has a class instead of an Id, you might want to look at this:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector
```